# Why does HttpRoute require IHttpRouteData to generate a virtual path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've been testing some ASP.NET Web API code that makes use of `UrlHelper`. I was finding that calls to `UrlHelper.Link` returned null. After much digging through the ASP.NET source I found that it was necessary to set the `IHttpRouteData` of the request in order for `HttpRoute.GetVirtualPath` to work as expected.

I'd like to understand why this is necessary especially since it doesn't appear to matter what we set the route data to, just that it is there. For example, to test outbound URL generation the following works:

```
private string GenerateURL(string routeName, object routeValues = null)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/");
    request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] 
        = new HttpRouteData(new HttpRoute()); // this has to be set

    var dict = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
    // Have to add "httproute" route value to ensure url is generated
    dict.Add("httproute", true);

    var vp = httpConfiguration.Routes.GetVirtualPath(request, routeName, dict);

    if (vp == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return vp.VirtualPath;
}
```